Synonyms seem to behave differently when searching for them
Usually, if tag [a] is a synonym of [b] then searching for [a] will only return a search for [b]. Because, for all intents and purposes, they are the same tag and the synonym direction determines one as the main public-facing tag, the other being replaced with the main tag on almost every occasion.
That does not seem to be the case any more. Now searching for [a] brings you to a page with the search query [a] or [b].
As a demonstration ux is a synonym of user-experience and clicking on the former tag leads to a page with a query for both of them:

Moreover, this behaviour is different when you use a compound search query that includes a synonym and anything else. In that case, we get the old behaviour of directly substituting the synonyms: searching for [ux] or [ad] transforms to a search for [user-experience] or [advertising].
Is this working as intended (a new feature) or not working as intended (a bug)?

Perhaps important distinction to know: tag synonym vs tag merging. Unmerged tags will keep both source tag and target tag intact. Thus, directly substituting the synonyms may leave out the source tag from the result.

This is by design. You can refer to my answer on a separate post here.
Basically, we changed this behavior to make sure that there were no tags that are simply not searchable. It's not an all-encompassing fix (complex query behavior remains the same) but it at least makes those previously unsearchable questions accessible.
Thanks for bringing it up; I'm open to feedback on our approach!

Can the FAQ posts please be updated whenever a change is made to a fundamental system component? For instance, in this case, the tag synonym and merged tag FAQ still says that tag synonyms redirect in search. Doing so will prevent confusion on the part of users who don't frequent MSO or another per-site meta whenever a system change is made.

Also, another bug: going to the search box, (possibly) typing something extra there, and doing the search causes the master tag to show up twice. For instance, in the question's example, it will show up as "[user-experience] or [user-experience]".

This makes it more confusing, and IMO is a step back, not forward. If I'll be able to think of a better way I'll write a post, but personally would just prefer to see it rolled back.
